How do I select(?) an element in a 3D array and place the appropriate elements into another array? Powershell
Here is a portion of the code.
$importData = @()
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $importData1.Count; $i++) {
    Write-Host "Debug: Variable `$i is $i"
    switch -Regex ($importData1.Vlan[$i]) {
        { ($_ -match '2') -or ($_ -match '1') } { 
            switch -Regex ($importData1.IP[$i]) {
                '^\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$' {
                    # For Jungee Mixer/Screen
                    $a, $b = $($importData1.Device[$i]).Split('/')
                    $c, $d = $($importData1.IP[$i]).Split('/')
                    $importData += @{Device = "$c"; IP = "$a" }
                    $importData += @{Device = "$d"; IP = "$b" }
                }
.....


Here is a portion of the first array:
Device                        VLAN  IP
------                        ----- --
Laundry Controller (WAN)      2.00 10.20x.yy.zz
VLAN 20 (Spare Port)          2.00
Accudate Food Labeler (PAR)   1.00 zz.00

My first issue is that the "$importData1.Vlan[$i]" does not give me element 2's VLAN entry. I have to use $importData1[$i] which will give me the second element but will not give me the VLAN entry.
I'm sure that there is a simple solution that I must be overlooking.
My second issue i'm sure is caused my the first. Nothing is being added to the second array.
I have tried. "$importData1[1].Vlan" with no success.

You probably want $inportData1[$i].Vlan -

Apologies, i should i added that i've tried that and it did not work.

That would suggest $importData1 doesn't actually contain the data you've described :) When $i = 1, $importData1[$i] will absolutely give you the seond item in the $importData1 array, so if $importData1[$i].VLAN doesn't evaluate to anything then either $importData1 has no item in slot 2, or the item either has no VLAN property or one that's empty :)

Thank you so much! There happened to be a space in the "VLAN " heading in the excel sheet which is why i was unable to access the VLAN property. It included a space. I appreciate your help!
